# Best way to substitute both K&V based on a map?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping, substitution

Let say we have a map-dict and data-dict :

```
m = { 1:2, 4:5, 3:7 }
data = { 1:7, 4:1, 3:6 }
```

we should replace all occurrences both key&val in "data" according to "m" :

```
data1 = { 2:7, 5:2, 7:6 }
```

what is the shortest, fast way to do this ?

I was thinking of converting data to list do the replacements and convert back to dict. But even that gets too involved.

Converting list to dict is OK :

```
dict(zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2]))
```

Converting dict to list is :

```
data.items()
```

but this one does not return list, but list of tuples, which make things too involved i.e we need to additionally flatten this LoT.

I was wondering if there is a better way, with emphasis on speed/mem.

Comment: I guess you're using [tag:python-3.x]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dict comprehension:

```
data1 = {m.get(k, k): m.get(v, v) for k, v in data.items()}
```

Note that `{4: 1, 4: 6}` in your example is a single element.